# predict all test batches in keras / tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-datasets

i am trying to predict all my test batches in keras / tensorflow to then plot a confusion matrix.
The current `BATCH_SIZE` is: 32

My test dataset is generated with the following code from a big dataset:

```
test_dataset = big_dataset.skip(train_size).take(test_size)
test_dataset = test_dataset.shuffle(test_size).map(augment).batch(BATCH_SIZE)
```

After `model.compile()` and `model.fit()` i get the predictions and the correct labels with this code:

```
points, labels = list(test_dataset)[0]
preds = model.predict(points)
preds = tf.math.argmax(preds, -1)
points = points.numpy()
```

This method only predicts one batch --> 32 predictions.

Is there a way to predict all test batches in keras / tensorflow?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could pass the entire dataset to `model.predict` according to the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#predict):

> Input samples. It could be: A Numpy array (or array-like), or a list
> of arrays (in case the model has multiple inputs). A TensorFlow
> tensor, or a list of tensors (in case the model has multiple inputs).
> A tf.data dataset. A generator or keras.utils.Sequence instance. A
> more detailed description of unpacking behavior for iterator types
> (Dataset, generator, Sequence) is given in the Unpacking behavior for
> iterator-like inputs section of Model.fit.

```
points = test_dataset.map(lambda x, y: x)
labels = test_dataset.map(lambda x, y: y)
preds = model.predict(points)
preds = tf.math.argmax(preds, -1)
```

Or with `numpy`:

```
points = np.concatenate(list(test_dataset.map(lambda x, y: x))
labels = np.concatenate(list(test_dataset.map(lambda x, y: y))
preds = model.predict(points)
preds = tf.math.argmax(preds, -1)
```